# Eclipse RCP application with command line argument having embedded spaces

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to pass in the working directory to an RCP program using arguments so it works from the IDE and an exported product.  When the working directory has spaces the command line argument does not work correctly.  I have tried various combinations of double and single quotes with out getting the right directory.

Works correctly

myapp -data @user.home/MyApp/

Works incorrectly by setting the directory to @user.home/My/

-data @user.home/My Documents/MyApp

What is the correct syntax for passing command line arguments with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-data @user.home/"My Documents"/MyApp
```

Regards

**Edit 1**

Can you try the following way

```
-data @user.home/My\ Documents/MyApp
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it results in @user.home/My/.

Comment: same result @user.home/My/  I'm going to just use a property in config.ini since that works correctly for the exported product.